# Can I export an InDesign / Illustrator file to pdf with a different print version?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign, pdf, document-setup

I'm creating a single page invitation with a dark background and white text. The invitation will be sent via e-mail. However, when people print the invitation, I would like the print to have a white background with dark text (to save ink).

Does anybody know whether this is possible, and how? I use either InDesign or Illustrator to design the invitation.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You could achieve that by Making the design into a html email instead of a pdf... Which admittedly can have its own issues.

Comment: Why is sending 2 separate files, one for print one for proofing, not an option? This is how almost every design/print house works

Comment: @Ovaryraptor, I'm just guessing here, but I was under the impression  the invitation is sent to invitees via email and he wanted the design to be black because aesthetics, but he doesn't want to drain all ink from the printers of those who wish to print it. That said, that's more or less what I was thinking too. Maybe it'd be possible to send like a jpg or png with the black design and include a link to "print version" or just attach it. Since html emails can be a pain and/or outside of his wheelhouse.

Comment: @Joonas Ahh that makes more sense. Yeah, a jpg print version with instructions to print that would be the easiest option.

Comment: Thanks both for your ideas! Its probably going to be two different files now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, it is **not** possible to somehow embed a "print variation" within a PDF which is different than the displayed artwork. And I'm certain neither InDesign nor Illustrator have *any* options for anything even remotely close to this.

The only exception may be *watermarks/stamps* Within Adobe Acrobat itself. Watermarks can be set to only display upon printing. But they will be shown on top of the displayed artwork. So, you still could not change black to white upon printing.